# Cdatabase in MFC

Tags: c++, database, oracle, mfc

How to use CDatabase object to connect oracle database in mfc?
Please suggest any tutorial or an example

Comment: I suppose you need to write appropriate initialization string with correct OLEDB driver in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDatabase normally uses an OLE DB or ODBC connection to the database.

Uisng ODBC, (nearly?) everything specific to the database server is going to be contained in the ODBC connection definition rather than the client code -- you could, for example, switch an ODBC connection to connect to MS SQL server one time, MySQL the next, and Oracle the third time, all with no modification of the client code.

Using OLE DB, a little more of the work ends up in the client, but @Kirill is pretty much right: most of connecting to one DB server another comes down to the connection string. The VS AppWizard can create at least a starting point for a connection string. The big thing you want/need to change is if you've given a user-name and password to AppWizard, they'll be embedded in the connection string. That's generally unacceptable for real code -- at least the password generally needs to come from somewhere at least semi-secure (e.g., entered by the user but not stored, at least not permanently).